# Use Other Rather than Primary Email in Smarty Template

Tags: message-templates, smarty

We have Civi CRM 5.53 and I am looking to show people what their registration email is for an event.  I am having to use civi rules and so I'm looking to use a Message Template with SMARTY to show the email address.  However, I want it to be the 'Other' email address (which is what's captured in our profile for registering participants) rather than the primary one.  Is there any way of showing the 'Other' email address rather than the primary one in a template?

We use Wordpress.